# android studio idea adb continue reconnect

Tags: android, adb

my android studio adb continue reconnect fail;

I try to restart my idea but not effected;

android studio event log:

```
Unable to detect adb version, exit value: 0x8f
```

plz help me

Answer (score 0):

i find answer ,my company ban adb server LOL